# Cannot clone with Git though all permissions have been set up

Tags: git

I am the owner of an Assembla-account with a Git repository. I tried to clone it and have authentication errors.

What did I do? I created a folder, did `git init` to create the initial `.git` directory. Then I added per-project an user-name and -email via

```
git config user.name "myproject" # Set your name
git config user.email "myproject@mymail.com" # Set an email
```

Then I created a new SSH key via `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myproject@mymail.com"` and uploaded it to the SSH key manager at Assembla's project page.

After that I tried `git clone git@git.assembla.com:myproject.git`, but still get the error

```
ERROR -- : permission denied
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Why do I still have authentications errors? If I open `.git/config`, I can see the proper user-name and -email set in the `[user]` section.

PS.: I intentionally did not change the global user-name and -email, but for this project only, since my global credentials are for multiple other projects.

Comment: Have you added that key? ssh-add path-to-private-key, I think it's assumed the public is in the same folder.

Comment: Is `ssh git@git.assembla.com` working?

Comment: Just a foodnote. There is no need to git init if you are cloning a repo.

Comment: Know that the contents of your `.git/config` file are irrelevant - the problem you have is almost certainly that the ssh key you've put on your assembla account doesn't match the one you're using when you try to clone. the output of `ssh -vvv git@git.assembla.com` would confirm that.

Comment: @dutt The SSH key has been added both to the Assembla server and it's in my /home/.ssh/ directory

Comment: @RonniSkansing If I don't do `git init`, I would not have `myproject/.git/config` file but Git will try to pull credentials from the global config file. I don't want that. How can I force git to pull auth data from the local config file instead of the global one?

Comment: When I gave SSH key its default name `id_rsa.pub`, the connection was accepted and I could pull the content from Git repository. 

Does SSH key name have to be `id_rsa.pub` always? I cannot use file name like `myproject_id_rsa.pub` so to have SSH key for every project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, you have a server that contains a number of different projects, and you have a different SSH identity (public key) for each project.

The username and email that you configure in git aren't used to select the credentials for the SSH connection; they are only/primarily used for putting the author and committer information into every commit.

To set up using the correct SSH identity for every remote repository, you need to use a `.ssh/config` file. The key configuration parameter is `IdentityFile`:

```
Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github.key
```

Because the identify file is defined per host and you seem to have multiple projects running on the same server, you will need some host alias trickery to assign the correct identity file to each project:

```
Host project1
    HostName my-server-address
    Port 22
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/project1.key

Host project2
    HostName my-server-address
    Port 22
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/project2.key
```

Then use `project1` and `project2` in your git clone URL instead of `my-server-address`.

There's a good, comprehensive description on how to do all this at [Simplify Your Life With an SSH Config File](http://nerderati.com/2011/03/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/).